# IDM-Like softwares in ubuntu

Tags: download-manager

Earlier I was using Windows 7. It was having IDM (Internet download Manager) from which I was able to download almost all the types of files from the internet. I was also able to download online streaming videos by the help of IDM. It was really helpful for me regarding the downloading. I was also able to resume my downloads which were paused or stopped due to some reason.

So, I would like to ask that whether there is any software in Ubuntu form which I could get these functions and if there is any software, then how to download it.

I am a new user in Ubuntu. I am using Kubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 9):

[image]

[uGet](http://ugetdm.com) is by far the best download manager for Linux because it has a ton of powerful features while at the same time is very lightweight in resource usage. uGet is just as fast as IDM. Unlike some of the other options on Linux, uGet is completely Open Source and does not limit the user for any reason.

For easily downloading videos from streaming sites you should look at FlashGot - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/?src=search

Answer (score 3):

I recommend **flareget**.Flareget is the best download manager program for linux.Its speed was high as compared to IDM in windows.

Download and install flareget from http://flareget.com/download/

Answer (score 1):

I think GetJet Download is Good one, Try it [Download Getjet](http://cylonlinux.weebly.com/getjet.html)

[image]