# Change default downloader in Firefox or Chromium

Tags: downloads, browser

I want to download all types of file with Firefox or Chromium web browser directly with a downloader without copying and pasting the link.

Comment: Which downloader are you using? does it provide browser integration? Some also provide auto link recognition(i.e you don't need to copy paste link). what research have you done? Please add more information.

Comment: for FF [downThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) can be a good tool to have..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is old, but anyway:

**In Firefox** there are different solutions:

- Install [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/downthemall/) addon.

  To be sure it appears as an option in the *Save as* dialog: go to the addon's options and check that

[image]

To improve speed maximize the number of connections in preferences (now up to 10 connections per download):

[image]

Then when downloading select one of the DTA options in that dialog:

[image]

- To set a custom downloader in Firefox, install [Flashgot addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/flashgot/) Then, in the addon's preferences add the custom downloader (General>'Add'). It can be DownThemAll (which doesn't need this to work, as seen above) or some other downloader, the best maybe being [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/). uGet is added automatically to FlashGot once installed. (Go to *Catagory>Properties>Default for new download* to maximize the number of connections - up to 16)

**In Chrome** there are different download managers that exist as apps or extensions that evolve in time, like at the present moment [Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn) (which supports up to 5 connections per download).

NAPI plugins are not supported anymore and this limits a lot the options available for Chrome.

[FlareGet](https://flareget.com/) is a commercial downloader that has integration with both Firefox and Chrome through specific addons.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using internet download manager in windows, and can't say it works on ubuntu or not (for example under wine), but here you can find recomendations about download managers in ubuntu [IDM-Like softwares in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366525/idm-like-softwares-in-ubuntu)