# how can i download videos from the internet

Tags: video, downloads

how can I download videos from the internet like I was doing in windows "Downloading them by IDM" ? is there any application or program to do that ?? 
I searched a lot but I couldn't find any solutions, Ubuntu is a great OS, it must be a way to do that !!!! please help!

Comment: In order to answer your question one would have to know how were you doing it in Windows. There are hundreds of ways or tools for that and many do not depend on the OS. For example, any browser addon is OS independent (there are dozens for the purpose for Firefox or Chrome and others. Most standalone apps are also multi-platform so chances are you can use the same. Now please edit and update your question.

Comment: Also, download videos from where? There are huge differences between downloading videos from Netflix, YouTube, Dailymotion, and random websites.

Comment: i'm new to Ubuntu, on windows all you have to do is to install the IDM and download what ever you want from anysite!

Comment: Many recommendations here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/366525/idm-like-softwares-in-ubuntu and also this older one http://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/what-download-managers-are-available-for-ubuntu . I use mostly the Video DownloadHelper FF addon and sometimes JDownloader. Feel free to try other suggestions in the links above and also feel free to ignore any answers suggesting command line tools like `youtube-dl` because clearly that's not what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDM-Like softwares in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/366525/idm-like-softwares-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Since you mentioned you want to "download videos from the internet," see also [How do I download a YouTube video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video) and [How to download flash (streaming) videos from sites like youtube, dailymotion, vimeo, etc.?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11211/how-to-download-flash-streaming-videos-from-sites-like-youtube-dailymotion-v)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a YouTube video?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/63270/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video)

Comment: use this extension, it has a native Linux app https://www.downloadhelper.net/install-coapp?browser=firefox

Answer (score 6):

I use [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/) on my ubuntu 16.04

**Installation :**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install uget
```

[image: UGet]

- To integrate **uGet** to Firefox browser, install [FlashGot addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/).

  Once installed, in Firefox menu go to **Tools** > **FlashGot** > **More Options**

  Under **Download Manager**, choose **uGet**

  [image: FlashGot]

  Now, you can right-click the link and choose FlashGot Link option

  [image: FlashGot Right Click]
- For download **video**:

  in Firefox menu go to **Tools** > **FlashGot** > **More Options**

  choose FlashGot Media

  Under **Download Manager**, choose **uGet** and tick **Show toolbar button**

  [image: configure FlashGot Media with uGet]

  go to play video in *ex: youtube* and in toolbar will be there is icon like this [image: icon FlashGot Media]

  right click the icon, choose Available formats to download. then OK.

  [image: FlashGot Media]

  [image: uGet Media]
  That's it

Comment: I cannot use the Firefox addon with Firefox Quantum 59.0.2. because it's not compatible. Is this just me?

Answer (score 4):

`youtube-dl` is my personal favorite for downloading YouTube videos. To download this simply type these commands into terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Then all you need to do is type `youtube-dl youtube.link` in a terminal and it downloads that YouTube video.

Comment: The user wants a **graphical** download manager also able to download from video streaming sites.

Comment: [ClipGrab](https://clipgrab.org/) is awesome

Comment: @CelticWarrior The OP has (unfortunately) not been very specific about what they would find useful, and hasn't mentioned anything about graphical interfaces. They mentioned IDM, which is a GUI application for Windows, but, unless I'm missing something, they haven't said specifically what things about IDM are important to them. So I think this answer is as reasonable as any.

Answer (score 1):

- try using DownThemAll addon in mozilla Ubuntu, it's great and boosts your download acceleration like "IDM"
- Installing DownThemAll 
  in mozilla browser->Menu->Addons->DownThemAll
- you have multiple options in DownThemAll
  -like downloading all the links in current tab using **dTa Oneclick(current Tab),
  dTa Oneclick(All Tabs),Download Manager.**
- you can use all these extensions by going to customize option in menu and drag and drop all them to tool bar of your browser.
- go to the page where your file exists , right click on that file and click on download with DownThemAll option.
- for more info go here http://www.downthemall.net/